# Why should I treat adding `fowardRef` in a React library as a breaking change?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, semantic-versioning, react-ref

[The React docs state that when a React component library starts using `forwardRef` that change should be a breaking change and a new major version of the library should be released.](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#note-for-component-library-maintainers).

My team is considering a change that would add `forwardRef` to a component in our library but it's not clear to us why the React team states this should be a breaking change.

Our current implementation looks like this:

```
// Without ref
const MyComp = (props) => <SomeJsx {...props}/>;
```

And we plan to change it to:

```
// With ref
const MyComp = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <SomeJsx ref={ref} {...props}/>);
```

In the case without `forwardRef`, if the `ref` prop is passed to the component React with throw an error (in dev mode) that states:

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

While this error could be ignored, it does indicate React sees `ref` as a "reserved prop" so consumers of our library should not be using it. Based on this it seems to me that this change fits [semver's](https://semver.org/) description of a minor change in that we're essentially adding a new prop.

Can someone explain why updating a React component to use `fowardRef` should be considered a breaking change? The docs provide a couple reasons but there are no examples and the wording implies that adding `fowardRef` may not always be a breaking change. I'd like to understand this situation better so I can make an informed decision.

I've created an example here to test compatibility with respect to semver breaking changes.

[Link to example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/forwardref-breaking-change-n7fgfe?file=/src/App.tsx)

Based on the console warning about supplying a `ref` prop to the component without `forwardRef` indicates that React is reserving the `ref` prop so no users should be using this prop. Granted the app still seems to run fine and users can ignore this error but I generally think it's not a component library's responsibility to handle "bad behavior" like this. So, from the perspective of adding support for the `ref` prop via `forwardRef` I don't see this as a breaking change.

Looking at the Typescript types is interesting because adding `forwardRef` is not type compatible with the existing component type which is written as

`const MyComp = (props) => <SomeJsx/>`

This is meant to be a `React.FunctionComponent` however, its Typescript type does not match. If we re-write the implementation like this

`const MyComp: React.FC<any> = (props) => <SomeJsx/>; // note:` any `used for demo purposes only`

then the Typescript types are compatible.

All of this leads me to the conclusion that, from a strict semver point of view this is a breaking change due to the change of Typescript types.

Does my assessment cover everything? What am I missing?